# Reset count in middle of WP_Query

Tags: wordpress, count, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I have a WP_Query querying CPT 'projects' for author details. When getting authors from an ACF repeater field, if there is more than one author I want to add the word 'and' between them.

Have this working just fine on on single-project but when I query all projects the count does not reset after subloop. Not sure if I need have to reset count and/or if I need to count the number of items in the repeater and if greater than 2 then run the code?

Either way, not sure how to do this and hoping someone might give me some pointers.

```
<?php
  $args = array(
 'post_type' => 'showcase',
 'posts_per_page' => -1,
 'orderby' => 'rand',
);
$projects = new WP_Query($args);
?>
<?php if($projects->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while($projects->have_posts()) : $projects->the_post() ?>
  // some content here
        <?php $i==1; while( have_rows('project_author') ): the_row(); ?>
        <?php if($i ==1)
        {
        echo "and";
        }; ?>
        <?php the_sub_field('screenwriters_name'); ?>
        <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
<?php  endwhile ?>
<?php endif ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Thx

Comment: You have an statement $i == 1 before comment // some content true. I think that you will need remove one equal symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the equality operator when attempting to set `$i` to 1. You need to use the assignment operator instead (single instead of double equals).

At the moment `$i` only becomes 1 after you run `$i++` which is going to result in some unexpected behaviour. The if statement inside your while loop to output 'and' would run on the first iteration of the loop if `$i` was being set to 1 correctly at the top of your code.

The other issue I see with the logic being used is 'and' will only be output once regardless of how many authors are in the repeater field.

There are a few ways you could approach this problem.

## Solution 1 - patching up the errors

```
<?php while ( $projects->have_posts() ) : $projects->the_post(); ?>

    <?php $i = 1; // fix assignment

    while( have_rows( 'project_author' ) ): the_row();

        // run on all iterations of the loop except the first.
        if ( $i > 1 ) {
            echo ' and '; // add space before and after string.
        }

        the_sub_field( 'screenwriters_name' );

        $i++;
    endwhile; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

## Solution 2 - treating the field as an array and using implode()

This solution feels cleaner to me. We're going to retrieve the author field as an array rather than looping through using the repeater functions (`have_rows()` / `the_row()`).

```
<?php while ( $projects->have_posts() ) : $projects->the_post(); ?>

    <?php $project_author = get_field( 'project_author' );

    if ( $project_author ) {

        // extract screenwriters_name values (the sub field name) from the fields array.
        $screenwriter_names = array_column( $project_author, 'screenwriters_name' );

        // join elements of the array into a string. ' and ' is only used when more than one.
        echo implode( ' and ', $screeenwriter_names );
    }  ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```